# Core Data Sorted relationship + NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a model with `Tag`s and `Document`s. Each Tag can have multiple Documents. Each document can have multiple Tags. In a Tag all the Documents are ordered. The Tag.Documents relationship is currently an NSSet, so it's unordered.

I am also using a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `NSSortDescriptor` that just returns the Documents in other of their creation-time property. But I need them to be in a different order depending on the Tag I'm currently displaying.

Having looked at multiple other SO questions it seems that using a `NSOrderedSet` might not offer the solution, so instead I am trying to add a third object `TagDocumentPair` that points to 1 Tag and 1 Document. Each tag and document will point to multiple TagDocumentPair objects. Pretty straight forward.

The question I have is how should I create the NSSortDescriptor?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:.managedObjectContext];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags contains %@",tag];
request.fetchBatchSize = 20;
request.sortDescriptors =
//  @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationTime" ascending:NO]];
```

This would probably be easy to do with a JOIN...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that a fetch request cannot sort the results according to an ordered relationship, so using an "intermediate" entity might be the only solution.

You would then execute a fetch request on the "TagDocumentPair" entity instead of the "Document" entity:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TagDocumentPair" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", selectedTag];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"orderNumber" ascending:NO]];
```

where "orderNumber" is an attribute of "TagDocumentPair" that describes the ordering
of the documents of a tag.

Since each "TagDocumentPair" points to exactly one "Document", you can display the
document attributes in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` etc.

A disadvantage of this solution might be that changes to the attributes of a "Document" will not automatically trigger table view updates, because a fetched results controller does
not track changes to related objects.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting solution! But unfortunately I am already relying on the `nsfrc` for updates. I'll look into Subqueries and Fetched Properties and see if they provide a better alternative. Or I could have a "orderInCurrentTag" property to documents that I write to before setting the `nsfrc`'s request, but that's seems way too hacky and may lead to performance issues later down the line. If I can't find another solution I'll have use this and use GCD for updating the tableview on attribute changes.

Comment: Well, sadly, I haven't managed to find a better solution to this. But I guess that putting a documentDidChange attribute on the TagDocumentPair and changing it's value whenever I change something in the Document might solve the issue of triggering updates without the need of adding other observers...

Comment: @LescaiIonel: Yes I think that is a good solution. You probably can make that attribute *transient*, so that it is not saved in the SQLite file.